# Php - String slices from a string which contains HTML tags and output in json

Tags: php, html, json

I have a string which contains HTML tags and I want to cut slices of that string when these tags come:

```
<br>
<img>
<ifram>
```

This will clear you what I want to do. Let's say I have a String containing HTML tag is:

```
<b>hello this image </b><br><img src="https://www.example.com/abc.png"> 
is awesome<br><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ozt0" width="300" height="150"></iframe>awesome!
```

What I want to provide JSON output like this from an upper string:

```
{
   "text1" : "<b>hello this image </b>",
   "img" : "https://www.example.com/abc.png",
   "iframe" : "http://www.youtube.com/embed/ozt0",
   "text2" : "awesome!"
}
```

The output of data might be shuffled according to string and may contain 3-9 **images** or 2-4 **iframes** 20-50 **texts**

Or any other way to do a similar thing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is use DOMDocument to load the string, then use $dom->getElementsByTagName or XPATH to filter any elements / textnodes and get the contents that way.

Comment: No experience with JS I am new to php advance !

Comment: DOMDocument is available in PHP as well: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php